# How to put custom post taxanomies name only to array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

I have custom post types in wordpress. Custom post have taxonomies.

```
<?php
    $customQuery = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'custom'
    ]);
    while ($customQuery->have_posts()) {
        $customQuery->the_post();
        print_r(the_taxonomies());
    }
?>
```

**Result**:

```
Array
(
    [portfolio_tag] => Taxonomies: <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/custom_tag/app/">App</a> and <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/custom_tag/developer/">Developer</a>.
)
```

How to get all taxonomies name to array in wordpress?

```
Array
(
   'App',
   'Developer'
)
```

Comment: try get_terms();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_object_terms` or `wp_get_post_terms` If it's not working then you replace function `wp_get_object_terms` to `wp_get_post_terms`

In `wp_get_object_terms` and `wp_get_post_terms` function have 2 perameters 1st is post id and 2nd is custom-taxonomy-name, So you can pass the second parameter here

For knowledge

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

and

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

```
<?php
    $customQuery = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'custom'
    ]);
    while ($customQuery->have_posts()) {
        $customQuery->the_post();
        $arr_get_terms = wp_get_object_terms($customQuery->ID, 'custom-taxonomy-name-here');
        print_r($arr_get_terms);
    }
?>
```